# What is a boilerplate code for connecting to Cloud Firestore from within Cloud Function?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'm looking for boilerplate snippets for both index.js and package.json to connect from my Node.js cloud function to Cloud Firestore database under the same project with a simple read/update request as example.

ps I'm using Cloud Functions inline editor.

Comment: Are you looking for [initilalizing Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart#initialize) ? just make sure you are on NodeJS tab.

Comment: Thanks, it helps! I still don't understand what dependencies I should put to package.json

Comment: ok, figured out: "firebase-admin": "^10.0.2"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting link from one of the comments that helped me.

[Initialize Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart#initialize)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).